# PHP Multidimensional Array Megre

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "product_id" => "8"
    "qty" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "product_id" => "9"
    "qty" => 2
  ]
]
```

and I would like to merge a static associative array `['invoice_id' => 1]` in to all the arrays in the multidimensional array. and the end result should be something like this

```
    array:3 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => "8"
        "qty" => 1,
        "invoice_id" => 1
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => "9"
        "qty" => 2,
        "invoice_id" => 1
      ]
    ]
```

is there a way to do this with out looping through the multidimensional array

Comment: You cannot do this without looping. It is either an explicit loop like `foreach` or an implicit one with `array_map`, `array_walk` functions. So please don't complicate the task. Do it as simple as possible.

Comment: any efforts from your side so far?

Comment: without looping not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Array_Map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

suppose Array data store in `$testArray` variable

```
$testArray= array_map(function($arr){
    return $arr + ['invoice_id' => 1];
}, $testArray);
```